# Не добавляется пагинация

Tags: javascript, jquery

При динамическим создании  элементов не работает пагинация, в коде использовал `bootstrap pagination`

**Вопрос:**  как инициализировать элементы в `DOM`?

1. Доп. ссылка кода на [планкер](http://plnkr.co/edit/JxU4JvdCDn7JOmB7uzg2?p=preview)
2. Пример брал  [тут](http://jsfiddle.net/5HA8g/)

**Алгоритм**  при нажатии кнопки "добавить" добавляется строка в таблице.

Если таблица статическая `html` то пагинация с нумерацией есть (он работает нормально), а в моем случае строки в таблице добавляются динамически по нажатию кнопки и в этом случае нумерации нет, то есть получается что для элементов не существовавших в DOM c самого начала скрипт (смотреть ссылку по пункту 2, он же присутствует в моем коде) для таблицы не видит их этих элементов

```
document.querySelector('#createD').onclick = function() {
    var htb = document.getElementById('htb');
    var row = document.createElement("div");
    row.className = "t-row";
    row.innerHTML = "<div class='col-1'><input class='checkbox' type='checkbox' name='domename'></div>" +
      "<div class='col-2'><div><i class='site-ico'></i><a href='#' class='domen-name'>www.example</a></div></div>";
    tba.insertBefore(row, null);

  },
  document.querySelector('#removeD').onclick = function() {
    var row = document.getElementsByClassName('t-row');
    var domename = document.getElementsByName('domename');
    for (i = 0; i < domename.length; i++) {
      if (domename[i].checked) {
        var remElm = domename[i];
        var tba = document.getElementById("tba");
        remElm.parentNode.removeChild(remElm);
        tba.removeChild(row[i]);
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: И где описание требуемого функционала? Что это за полотно кода? Вы думаете кому-то хочется разбираться с этой простыней без описания?

Comment: VenZell, вы уж простите делаю в спешке. Там все понятно.

Comment: Ведизелл верно говорит - разбираться в этой куче никто не будет. Нужен **минимальный** пример.

Comment: "Другой", тогда я вас прошу никак не отвечать, идите мимо.

Comment: Так я и не ответил. А с таким отношением к попытке наставить Вас на путь Истинный, Вы вряд ли заработаете желание помочь Вам у кого-либо.

Comment: я указал ссылку на планкер, я солидарен с теми кому неинтересен мой вопрос, пожалуйста ни принимайте близко к сердцу. А я уж сам докопаюсь до истины раз так. Возник вопрос я его задал. И тот обьем кода который есть его достаточно и меньше его не должно быть. он явно будет больше.

Comment: Вопрос, может и интересен, но сами подумайте - будет ли кто-то тратить N человекочасов/минут ради того, чтобы просто вникнуть в вопрос? Именно поэтому пример должен быть небольшим - ~10 строк, наверное.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/44800/discussion-between-radik-zu-and-other).

Comment: уменьшил обьем как просили